# How to load all Vue SFC in a specific directory in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-component, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I want to load all components in a specific directory and display it in a single page using Nuxt.

Something like this,

```html
<template>
  <component :is="view" v-for"view in extensions" :key="view" />
<template>

<script>
const fs = require("fs");

Array.prototype.last = function () {
  return this[this.length - 1];
};

const sfc = fs
  .readdirSync("monitors")
  .filter((filename) => filename.split(".").last() == "vue")
</script>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const extensions = ref(sfc);
</script>
```

I cant find any way to make it possible, I'm thinking it's impossible or I'm missing something important.

Comment: Do you want to change the directory where the files are read? Or something different? Your use-case seems quite unique and unclear as of right now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to read the file as text with `fs`. `fs` is a nodejs module and it won't work in client side. Not to mention you will have a hard time actually instanciating your components this way.

You can just use a glob import for the directory:

```html
<template>
  <component :is="view" v-for"view in extensions" :key="view" />
</template>

<script setup>
import * as extensions from '@/components/extensions'
</script>
```

You just need to create an `index` file in your directory and export all your components. This is sadly a required manual step, this file won't update itself when you add a new component.

```bash
|- extensions
 \_ index.js
 \_ Extension1.vue
 \_ Extension2.vue
```

```js
// index.js
export { default as Extension1 } from './Extension1.vue'
export { default as Extension2 } from './Extension2.vue'
```